# Make use of index when JOIN'ing against multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, indexing

Simplified, I have two tables, `contacts` and `donotcall`

```
CREATE TABLE contacts
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    phone1 varchar(20) NULL,
    phone2 varchar(20) NULL,
    phone3 varchar(20) NULL,
    phone4 varchar(20) NULL
);
CREATE TABLE donotcall
(
    list_id int NOT NULL,
    phone varchar(20) NOT NULL
);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_donotcall_list_phone ON donotcall
(
    list_id ASC,
    phone ASC
);
```

I would like to see what contacts matches the phone number in a specific list of DoNotCall phone.
For faster lookup, I have indexed `donotcall` on `list_id` and `phone`.

When I make the following JOIN it takes a long time (eg. 9 seconds):

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id
FROM contacts c
JOIN donotcall d
    ON d.list_id = 1
    AND d.phone IN (c.phone1, c.phone2, c.phone3, c.phone4)
```

[image: Screenshot of execution plan]

[Execution plan on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/CqstXng6)

While if I LEFT JOIN on each phone field seperately it runs a lot faster (eg. 1.5 seconds):

```
SELECT c.id
FROM contacts c
LEFT JOIN donotcall d1
    ON d1.list_id = 1
    AND d1.phone = c.phone1
LEFT JOIN donotcall d2
    ON d2.list_id = 1
    AND d2.phone = c.phone2
LEFT JOIN donotcall d3
    ON d3.list_id = 1
    AND d3.phone = c.phone3
LEFT JOIN donotcall d4
    ON d4.list_id = 1
    AND d4.phone = c.phone4
WHERE
    d1.phone IS NOT NULL
    OR d2.phone IS NOT NULL
    OR d3.phone IS NOT NULL
    OR d4.phone IS NOT NULL
```

[image: Screenshot of execution plan]

[Execution plan on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/au5u51cj)

My assumption is that the first snippet runs slowly because it doesn't utilize the index on `donotcall`.
So, how to do a join towards multiple columns and still have it use the index?

Comment: What you actually need to do is fix your datbase structure. You should NEVER have phone1, phone2, phone3, phone4 - that indicates you need a child table.

Comment: @HLGEM: Point noted. I would also have done it differently if I have had the choice. But sometimes you are stuck with a structure that others have created, without hopes of refactoring.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL Server might think resolving `IN (c.phone1, c.phone2, c.phone3, c.phone4)` using an index is too expensive.

You can test if the index would be faster with a hint:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM contacts c
JOIN donotcall d with (index(IX_donotcall_list_phone))
    ON d.list_id = 1
    AND d.phone IN (c.phone1, c.phone2, c.phone3, c.phone4)
```

From the query plans you posted, it shows the first plan is estimated to produce 40k rows, but it just returns 21 rows.  The second plan estimates 1 row (and of course returns 21 too.)

Are your [statistics](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190397.aspx) up to date?  Out-of-date statistics can explain the query analyzer making bad choices.  Statistics should be updated automatically or in a weekly job.  Check the age of your statistics with:

```
select  object_name(ind.object_id) as TableName
,       ind.name as IndexName
,       stats_date(ind.object_id, ind.index_id) as StatisticsDate
from    sys.indexes ind
order by 
        stats_date(ind.object_id, ind.index_id) desc
```

You can [update them](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx) manually with:

```
EXEC sp_updatestats;
```

Comment: Good suggestion. I tried to add the hint. However, it didn't change anything. The LEFT JOIN version is still a lot faster. It seems as if SQL server isn't able to resolve the code using the index.

Comment: Have you tried comparing the query plans?  (Menu Query, then Include Actual Execution Plan.)

Comment: I am trying to do that, but I have very little experience in analysing query plans. From what I can see, the LEFT JOIN solution is quite straight forward, using 4 Hash Matches (Right Outer Joins). The single JOIN solution does it completely differently. Two nested loops (Inner Joins), first with the index and then with the contacts table.

Comment: Are there any free online services allowing you to upload and visualize query plans to share with others?

Comment: You can export it as XML and put it on http://pastebin.com/.  Others can visualize the plan using the free http://www.sqlsentry.net/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view.asp

Comment: I've uploaded the execution plans on Pastebin and linked it in the question.

Comment: I have tried to update the stats, but the result was the same. Seems it doesn't know how to resolve in any better way. But, from your answer I've been learning a lot more about execution plans. So, while I might not be able to speed up this query, I now know better how to analyze other queries. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

With this poor database structure, a UNION ALL query might be fastest.

Comment: While UNION ALL currently performs better than the single JOIN solution, it is a bit slower than the LEFT JOIN solution.